# Does useState cause rendering if initial value is an function with extensive computation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning react hooks and need some clarity on this.

Consider the below code:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
  const initialState = someExpensiveComputation(props);
  return initialState;
});
```

If the dom has rendered and then the someExpensiveComputation is completed, Will react rerender the dom after that?

Any help will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It won't render again but in the same time it will wait until the calculation ends because it is a synchronous operation, cannot handle initial calculation asynchronously.

Better option from user experience and application performance perspective is to avoid big calculation when creating state objects with [`useState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). Instead you can use [`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> The Effect Hook lets you perform side effects in function components.

For example with empty dependency array it will be executed only once:

```
const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
   const value = someExpensiveComputation(props);
   setResult(value);   
}, []);
```

At the end this solution will cause a render again but you can handle it in your `return` statement as below:

```
return <>
   {
      result && <p>Result: {result}</p>
   }
<>
```

I hope that helps!